# WinCE VS2008 connect to device failed on emulator when physical device is not connected

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-ce, activesync

I'm doing some development on a WinCE device (Windows Handheld Embedded 6.5.3 to be exact) device lately. I've had the application running well on the device, on emulators, and on PC (I even created a desktop debugging environment using *Deploy to My Computer* by the Moth[1](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/deploy-to-my-computer.aspx)).

The application runs happily on all three platforms ONLY when a device is physically connected and active sync showing. If the device is unplugged from the wire, then start debugging by F5 targeting an emulator, even though the emulator then opens up and being able to connect to the Internet, there it goes "Deploy failed" on status bar of VS2008, and the error list showing "Connect to device failed".

I don't know why. Every post on the Internet says they have a problem with the device while the program runs fine on the emulator. My problem is the contrary. Has anyone came across this before?

Answer (score 0):

For the emulator WMDC needs to have Allow:DMA transport or you use Device Emulator Manager and dock the emulated, running, device-then WMDC shows connected and you can start a debug session without using DMA.

Hopefully you did not play with Tools-Options-Devices settings in VS, otherwise you should post your settings for review.

Note: VS remembers the last connected debug device. You should disconnect and turn off the real device after a debug session, before you start another debug session to another device (emulator or real one).

Comment: Thanks josef. I've tried your settings. You're right about VS remembering the last connect device. However I find it weird but true that disconnecting it does not suffice, unplugging the wire does it.

Comment: Unplugging alone may not work if the device has a wirelss connection. VS will then use the wireless IP of the device for the debug session and you may wonder why your application is starting on the first device although you plugged in another one.

Comment: Yes you're right. I noticed that because it does have WiFi. It's a Motorola MC65 by the way. Therefore I always press the power button when I'm done debugging one so that it cuts the connection.

Answer (score 0):

After all this time I realized I had a USB cable plugged into a USB port of my PC, which would not charge the device connected to it nor would it activate Microsoft Mobile Centre. Further exam showed that the USB port is faulty. Sometimes it works but sometimes it recognizes the USB connection, fires the "USB connected" sound of Windows but fails to to communicate any data. Unplug it and everything works fine. Even if when I plugged it to another port.

Hope this give a thought to anyone who believe their settings are correct but keep being bugged by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution contains multiple Projects, and I have several emulators configured for different hardware models. If any of the sub projects is set to use a different emulator, when the solution is started, multiple emulator will be started.

The same applies to real device, if any of the sub-project of the solution is set to use hardware device, regardless of the start-up project setting, the solution will report `Failed to connet`, since the sub-project was trying to connect to a real hardware device and it did fail, even if the start-up project was successfully deployed to emulator.

The solution:

Click **every** sub-project in `Solution Explorer`, make sure they are set to run with the **same** emulator in `Device` toolbar.